# Bind value to combobox in Edit mode in windows form app C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, data-binding, combobox

I have a list in which I put add and edit button. both of two button use the same form.
I use comboBox to add or edit person's role .This list is about the different role that a person can have so I need person's Id from table persons. In this case I add a combobox for user to lookup in person's table.
"add" button work successfully  but I do not know how to fetch person's name into combobox in edit mode. my code is like bellow :

in action of form load:

```
         var person = (from b in db.PersonRepository.GetAll()
                      select new { b.Id , Fullname = b.LName + " " + b.Name + "-" + 
             b.Id.ToString()  } ).ToList();
         person.Insert(0, new 
          {
             Id = 0,
               Fullname = "Please select one"
        });
        cmbSelectName.DisplayMember = "Fullname";
        cmbSelectName.ValueMember = "Id";
        cmbSelectName.DataSource = person;
```

and also I put code for edit record bellow above code :

```
                if (PersonRoleId != 0)
        {
            this.Text = "edit";
            btnAddOrEditPersonRole.Text = "edit";
            var personRole = db.PersonRoleRepository.GetById(PersonRoleId);
            var person1 = (from b in db.PersonRepository.GetAll()
                           where b.Id == personRole.PId
                           select new { b.Id, Fullname = b.LName + " " + b.Name + "-" + 
          b.Id.ToString() }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

            
            cmbSelectName.SelectedValue = person1.FullName;
     
            txtRolePost.Text = personRole.PersonPost;
            chbRolePersonStatus.Checked =(bool) personRole.Status;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

after searching I understand I should use

```
cmbSelectName.Text = person1.FullName;
```

instead of

```
cmbSelectName.SelectedValue = person1.FullName;
```

I just write the answer for anybody who has the same issue so do I